# better way to replace text

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am trying to separate a line of text with space in between.

here is my code

```
$Text= "hellohello"
if($Text -match "(\w+)(o)(\w+)") {$Text = ($Matches[1] + $Matches[2] -replace "o", "o ")+$Matches[3]}
```

What is a better way to do it? let's say if changed the text to "manymany", I want powershell to auto identifies the first word and add space in between.

Comment: Will the words always be repeated?  I.e., will there be lines of text like `yesyes` and `nono` and `maybemaybe`?  If so, it maybe as simple as 
```$text.Insert( $text.Length / 2, ' ' )```

Comment: Simple way if your words are the only thing in the string—> `$text -replace '^(\w+)\1$','$1 $1'`

Comment: Wow, Thanks for all the effort. That is opening so many doors for me. I like Glenn's solution. and Indeed the words always will be repeated. I should think of considering the $text.length. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask can be big and small. Identify a `word` programmatically is not an easy topic.

For your case, the easy one, I assume you just want to find the repeated `strings` and insert a space between.

The regular expression is easy enough to do it.

```
"yesyesnonolarryhellohello" -replace "(\w{2,}?)\1",'$1 $1'
```

Output

```
yes yesno nolarryhello hello
```

`.{2,}?` any string at least 2 characters, `()` to mark as a reference

`\1` to refer the first matched reference

so, `(.{2,}?)\1` can match `yesyes`, `okok` and `hellohello`, in such case, `$1` is the value of `yes`, `ok` and `hello`

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that 4 identically consecutive letters will add a space between them also. An example is `tallllamas`